# Combination lock java

Tags: java

For my program i am suppose to simulate a combination lock. so i ask the user to alter the combination lock to a new 3-number combination but it i dont know where i went wrong it seems to stay at (0,0,0)

```
public class Lock
{
private int xCombo;
private int yCombo;
private int zCombo;
private int top = 0;
public static boolean locked = false;

public Lock()
{
    xCombo = 0;
    yCombo = 0;
    zCombo = 0;
}

public void alter(int x, int y, int z)
{
    xCombo = x;
    yCombo = y;
    zCombo = z;
```

and from my demo class

```
public class LockDemo
{
public static void main(String [] arg)
{
    lockMenu();
}
public static void lockMenu()
{
    int x, y, z;
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    Lock newLock = new Lock();

    System.out.println("\nSelect an option for the lock.\n");
    System.out.println("    A : Set a new lock combination. ");
    System.out.println("    B : Close the lock.");
    System.out.println("    C : Attempt to open the lock.");
    System.out.println("    D : Check lock status.");
    System.out.println("    E : Check current top number.");

    char menuOption = kb.next().charAt(0);
    menuOption = Character.toUpperCase(menuOption);

    switch(menuOption)
    {
        case 'A':
        {
            System.out.println("Set a new combination for the lock.\n");

            System.out.println("Enter the first number of the combination.");
            x = kb.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter the second number of the combination.");
            y = kb.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter the third number of the combination.");
            z = kb.nextInt();

            newLock.alter(x,y,z);
            lockMenu();
```

Thanks for any help, if i need to post more of the code i will edit

Comment: You're creating a new `Lock`, which is initialized to `0, 0, 0`, every time you call `lockMenu`.

Comment: can you give me a hint on how to fix it? im kinda stuck on making the combination stick

Comment: What is your program supposed to do? Loop until the user says to exit? If so, use a while loop instead of recursion to accept user input (instead of `break` in your switch statment, you can use `continue` to go to the next iteration of a while loop).